# Display multiple h264 videostreams at fixed positions with gstreamer, Qt and weston

Tags: qt, gstreamer, wayland

I am trying to display multiple h264 videostreams from IP cameras on our embedded system (i.MX8 QXP) along with a Qt (5.14.2) application. Ideally we would like to position each video at a certain x & y with a certain width & height. We run weston with desktop-shell.

I have tried different approaches:

1. From the Qt application, make a process call to gst-launch-1.0
   For example to display one stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=50004 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encodingname=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! queue ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 mode=slave do-lost=false ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! imxvideoconvert_g2d ! waylandsink sync=false window-width=640 window-height=480
```

This gives acceptable latency, appears ontop of the application, but the position (x,y) is random.
I understand that the positioning is determined by the compositor (in this case desktop-shell) but is there any way around this? (looked up ivi-shell, but seems unsupported by gstreamer)

2. gst-launch with imxcompositor_g2d to combine multiple streams, for example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v imxcompositor_g2d name=comp \
sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=640 sink_0::height=480 \
sink_1::xpos=0 sink_1::ypos=480 sink_1::width=640 sink_1::height=480 ! \
waylandsink \
videotestsrc ! comp.sink_0 \
videotestsrc ! comp.sink_1
```

The problem with this approach is that xpos=0 seems to start at ~width/2, and I cannot move the image further to the left. Another problem is that the "width area" that is not covered by the video is filled with black color, instead of the showing the Qt application.

3. Let Qt application handle video stream

I use qml types MediaPlayer and VideoOutput to create a custom gsp-pipeline and display the video.
The problem with this approach is the added latency. By using the pipeline described in approach 1, and replacing waylandsink with qtvideosink, the latency is increased by more than ~2s.

```
        MediaPlayer {
            id:mediaPlayer2
            source: "gst-pipeline: udpsrc port=50004 caps=application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encodingname=H264,payload=96 ! queue ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 mode=slave do-lost=false ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! v4l2h264dec ! imxvideoconvert_g2d ! qtvideosink"
            autoPlay: true
            autoLoad: true
        }

        VideoOutput {
            width:640
            height:400
            x: 100
            y: 100
            source: mediaPlayer2
            z: 1
        }
```